# besides multiplying $\Sigma^{-1}$, how to solve U for $U\Sigma$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am learning this [MIT course](https://youtu.be/Yw1xmxPH_ps?t=592)

the lecturer is solving an unknown matrix

$$
U\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\sqrt{10} & 2\sqrt{10}\\  
\sqrt{10} & 2\sqrt{10}\\  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where

$$
\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2\sqrt{5}& 0& \\  
0& 4\sqrt{5}& \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

the lecturer claims that the solution is

> make these entries unit length

$$
U = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}& \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

when I get U, I can verify this solution is right, but how can I compute this solution when it is unknown?

we can use $\Sigma^{-1}$

$$\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} & 0\\0 & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{20}\end{matrix}\right]$$

but in some cases, $\Sigma^{-1}$ does not exist.

why is unit length a solution? besides multiplying $\Sigma^{-1}$, how to solve U?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix and $U$ is supposed to be orthonormal. If you write

$$ U \Sigma  = \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{10} & 2\sqrt{10} \\ \sqrt{10} & 2 \sqrt{10}\end{pmatrix}  $$

with $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \sqrt{5} & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \sqrt{5}\end{pmatrix}$ and let $U = \begin{pmatrix} a & b  \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$

When we multiply this way the columns are multiplied by the $\sigma_{1} , \sigma_{2}$

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{10} & 2\sqrt{10} \\ \sqrt{10} & 2 \sqrt{10}\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 2 a \sqrt{5} &  4 b \sqrt{5} \\  2 c \sqrt{5} &  4 d \sqrt{5} \end{pmatrix}  $$

then we have that

$$ -\sqrt{10} = 2 a \sqrt{5} \\ \sqrt{10} = 2 c \sqrt{5} \\ 2 \sqrt{10} = 4 b \sqrt{5} \\  2\sqrt{10} = 4d \sqrt{5} $$

which is the same as above

$$ - \sqrt{10} = 2 a \sqrt{5}  \implies a = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \sqrt{10} = 2c \sqrt{5} \implies c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

and then simplify the other

$$  2 \sqrt{10} = 4b \sqrt{5} \implies \sqrt{10} = 2 b \sqrt{5} $$

which is the same as above so

$$ b = d = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$

Answer (score 2):

You could write $$ U = \displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}a & b\\c & d\end{matrix}\right] $$
and then solve the equations that result from $$ U\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\sqrt{10} & 2\sqrt{10}\\  
\sqrt{10} & 2\sqrt{10}\\  
\end{bmatrix}.  $$

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward (but computationally involved) way to do this is the following: Let your unknown matrix consist of unknown constants,
$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}
 a & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, take this matrix, find the product $U \Sigma$, and set the result equal to the given matrix. This should allow you to solve for the constants $a$, $b$, $c$, and $ d$.